# svg element stretch

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I am creating a simple drawing application using SVG where a user can draw circles, rectangles, etc. and zoom in and out as necessary.

My main problem is stretch. I want to create a stretch button which will stretch all the SVG elements to the size of the browser without distorting it.

In my design the header takes 50 pixels and the footer takes 25 pixels. So the actual drawing space is minus that.

I haven't written any code and bbox and viewbox is getting me nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find drawable extrema and fit given bbox to visible web canvas.